# In the magicians, how does Julia meet the Brakebills guys and/or Filory?

Tags: the-magicians

I am not sure if I have skipped some chapter, because between Julia ascension (described at the end of 'The Magician King') and Julia teaming with the Brakebills (at the end of 'The Magicians') she should somehow find  about Filory, travel to Filory and meet the other travellers, Janet and Eliot, and Josh.

In 'The Magician King' it is mentioned that Julia has met Josh before, during the crossing to Filory, and also some remark is done insinuating she having passed more time there (albeit this could be just a posse/attitude related to her familiarity with nature magic), which could justify why Elliot and Janet team with her. But it also could be simply that they look into the past of Quintin for a suitable partner, or that the dean has been monitoring Julia progress. Whatever, is it described elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Janet and Eliot meet Julia while visiting a resort. Eliot tells Quentin in *The Magician King*:

> And then, like a dark angel of mercy come to safeguard my virtue, Julia appeared.
>
> At any rate the first time I laid eyes on our Julia she was being carried through the lobby strapped to a backboard, soaking wet and cursing a blue streak and insisting that she was fine, absolutely fine. Take your paws off me, you damned dirty apes.

I believe that this occurred chronologically sometime near the end of *The Magician* before the gang heads off to Fillory, but we are not told the whole story until the next novel.

Comment: And hard to say that it is the whole history but well, at least it is an anchor. It does not clarify why should them tell her of Filory, nor to speak of considering her a suitable queen.

Comment: But yes, I had forgotten this part.

Comment: Yeah, the next two books get into a lot of Julia-flashback to explain more of what's going on with her. So you'll get some explanation to some of your questions when you read them.

Answer (score 0):

End of season 1 ep. 5 "Penny's astral projection goes to a dungeon in a castle and see's that dissapeared girl in chains and the monster" and Season 1 ep. 6 Quentin explains what FILORY is: the World of Hobbits.
And that girl was Victoria, a Brakebills student who disappeared as part of that mysterious third year class several years ago. Penny remembers what he can of the place, drawing out a symbol that Kady makes him bring to Alice and Quentin. It’s Quentin who recognizes it. Pulling out one of his Fillory books, he shows an identical symbol. Penny didn’t just project himself — he projected himself to another world. Fillory, to be precise.